# C - Loading from file with fgets and sscanf

Tags: c, input, struct, spaces, scanf

In a function of my program I am trying to load data from a file into this struct array:

```
/* database struct */
typedef struct node {
    char       name[MAX];
    char       address[MAX];
    long int   number;
}record_type;

record_type record[100];
```

The function is as follows:

```
/* load database from disk */
void load_database() {
    char line[128];

    /* Set up database */
    database = fopen("database.txt", "r+w+a+");
    if(database == NULL) {
        printf("\n\tWARNING: No database found.");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Get database file from disk */
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), database) != NULL) {
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %lu", record[rec_num].name,
            record[rec_num].address, &record[rec_num].number);

        /* keeps track of array size */
        rec_num++;
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is inconsistencies with sscanf. If I include first and last name I cannot put a space between them or it places the first name in name[] and the last name in address[].

Here is a sample of the data I am trying to input from:

```
1.  Name: james manes       Address: 220 test addr      Number: 5558889999
```

I need to get the "james manes" into the name[] field, 220 test addr into the address[] field and 5558889999 into the number field of the struct. Is this possible at all?

Is there a more efficient way of managing this type of input?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you're trying to parse.

Comment: If you need to handle optional spaces in the input, and presumably in the address as well, it's tricky unless you have a reliable delimiter between fields in your input.  Either way, you might be better off with a regular expression parser (try `man 3 regex`).

Comment: @JimStewart I have never looked into regex. I'll look into that.

Comment: This should not be a problem if you *always* have both first & last names. It is only problematic if you sometimes supply a single name and sometimes two.

Comment: @Mawg I'm just wishing there was a way to say "Take all text after Name: and before Address and put it in name[]." etc. I'm going to try at least.

Comment: If you're going to do anything other than arithmetics on the phone numbers I suggest you store them as strings. That will simplify finding a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s"...` parses a whitespace delimited string in your input, so if you have spaces in the strings you want to parse, it won't work.

While you could use regexes to get what you want, since you use fixed strings as your markers, you could instead use `strstr` to pull out your strings:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), database) != NULL) {
    char *Name = strstr(line, "Name:");
    char *Address = strstr(line, "Address:");
    char *Number = strstr(line, "Number:");
    if (Name && Address && Number) {
        Name += strlen("Name:");
        *Address = '\0';
        Address += strlen("Address");
        *Number = '\0';
        Number += strlen("Number:");
        strcpy(record[rec_num].name, Name);
        strcpy(record[rec_num].address, Address);
        sscanf(Number, "%lu", &record[rec_num].number);
        rec_num++; } }
```

Note that this will also pull in all the whitespace around the name and address -- you can trim off leading and trailing whitespace if you want it cleaner.

Comment: I foresee this causing problems for my good friend, "Jonathon de l'Address: von Number: III"... :-P

Comment: I will be talking to my professor tomorrow about this and get his opinion.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you might want to take another look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/. Here you will see that the *str* argument is a pointer to a buffer (which you provided correctly) and then *num* is the amount of bytes you want to read **max**, which you did **not** provide correctly.

The problem with the amount of bytes passed to fgets in you piece of code is the incorrect use of the ***sizeof*** operator. The sizeof operator 'returns', as you probably know, the size of the give **type**. The type you are passing to sizeof is a pointer type (since an array in C for 99% the same as a pointer). The size of a pointer depends on the system you are running on (32 bits on Intel x86, 64bits on AMD64, 16bits on ATmega AVR, etc). So lets asume that you have a 64 bit machine, you will allow fgets to 'get' 64 bits (i.e. 8 bytes) of data, which is not what you want. What would be the correct statement then?

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(*line)*128, database) != NULL) {
    ...
```

What I'm doing here is dereferencing the *char pointer* to a *char* and multipling by the size of this array.

Then, secondly, your question about if this is possible: yes it is. I would like to ask a question myself now too. Is it necessary to do this in C (i.e. platform does not support anything different, learning purposes, etc) or can you also implement this in C#, Java, Python. If so I highly suggest you do.

And last but not least you are asking us about the usefulness of your code. That answer is really simple: no. Not in its current or fixed state. The problem you are having and much more complicated are fixed using a 'real' database (like MySQL) + its API.

Comment: This is not done for fun. This is for a class at my university for C and UNIX. I am learning C and I needed help with this small portion of my program. I appreciate the help, but please I do not need bold face type and it sounds as if you are talking down to me. Again, I do not appreciate that.

Comment: -1: while arrays can be silently converted to pointers many places, the operand of `sizeof` is not one of those places, and James' use of it is perfectly correct.